# How to get the document-level templates into Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)

Tags: vsto

"To summarize: if you install VSTO 2005 SE on top of a clean VS 2005 Professional, you won't have the document-level templates. If you want to have them you need to have VS 2005 Team Suite/Team Edition or you need to install the previous version of VSTO: VSTO 2005. So VS 2005 Professional + VSTO 2005 + VSTO 2005 SE will give you the document-level templates!"

So my question is, does anyone have a link to a VSTO 2005 download (it is no longer available from Microsoft).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/f2909f92-3517-49bc-9e86-c136299956bc/

> As Richard said earlier in this
>   thread, the "document-level" project
>   templates (Excel Workbook, Excel
>   Template, Word Document, and Word
>   Template) are not included in VSTO
>   2005 SE or Visual Studio 2005
>   Professional. To get the
>   "document-level" project templates in
>   the 2005 release of Visual Studio, you
>   must have one of the following
>   versions of Visual Studio:
>
> > Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office (this is a completely separate
> >     edition of Visual Studio for purchase;
> >     it is not a free download).
> >
> > One of the "Team System" versions of Visual Studio 2005.
>
> The VSTO development story is somewhat
>   simpler in Visual Studio 2008. In this
>   release, all of the VSTO projects
>   (add-ins and the document-level
>   projects) are now available in Visual
>   Studio 2008 Professional, as well as
>   the "Team System" versions. This
>   includes add-in and document-level
>   projects for both Office 2003 and the
>   2007 Microsoft Office system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will help [Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office 2005 Runtime (VSTO 2005 RTM)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5D3FECE9-74E0-4E19-AF98-AEDE2DF94F87&displaylang=en&displaylang=en)

> The VSTO 2005 redistributable package installs the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime, which is required to run solutions built using VSTO 2005. This runtime supports document-level customizations for Microsoft Office Excel 2003 and Microsoft Office Word 2003, and application-level add-ins for Microsoft Office Outlook 2003.

Comment: Thanks, but that is the version I have installed.  No document-level templates available.