# Creating a custom ribbon button in VS 2008 Standard

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vsto, ribbon, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I want to create a custom ribbon button within Outlook 2007 using Visual Studio 2008 Standard, but am unsure how to proceed.  Most of the [resources](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/DanielMoth/Office-Ribbon-Customisation-in-Visual-Studio-2008/) I've found mention VS 2008 Pro, and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279105/how-to-get-the-document-level-templates-into-visual-studio-tools-for-office-vsto/281346#281346) mentions that VSTO is not even included in Standard.

Is creating custom ribbon buttons possible using Visual Studio 2008 Standard?  If so, where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Adding Custom Dynamic Menus to the Office Fluent User Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462634.aspx) turns out to be a decent introduction, and [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57%28VS.80%29.aspx) to Office PIAs has also come in handy.